# 「自分の質問を自分で回答したい？」のポップアップに表示されるボタンのキャプションが英語

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

自分で質問した質問の「回答する」ボタンをクリックすると「自分の質問を自分で回答したい？」のポップアップが表示されます。
そのポップアップのボタンのキャプションが英語のままになっていました。

あと

ほかの回答に返事したい場合、「**コメント**」してください。

追加情報を付けたいなら、質問を「**編集**」してください。

という説明がしてありますが、このアスタリスクはもしかするとmarkdownの太字を意図して付けたアスタリスクではありませんか？
もしそうであれば太字の変換がうまくできていません。

Comment: possible duplicate of [英語が残っている+日本語に違和感: 自分の質問に自分で回答する時に出るダイアログ: Yes, I want to post an answer](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51/%e8%8b%b1%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%8c%e6%ae%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%ab%e9%81%95%e5%92%8c%e6%84%9f-%e8%87%aa%e5%88%86%e3%81%ae%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ab%e8%87%aa%e5%88%86%e3%81%a7%e5%9b%9e%e7%ad%94%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%99%82%e3%81%ab%e5%87%ba%e3%82%8b%e3%83%80%e3%82%a4%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0-yes-i-want-to-post-an-answer)

Comment: entoさん、ありがとうございます。確かに重複していますね。