# 英語が残っている: possible duplicate of コメント

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

重複を理由としてクローズ票を入れたら自動で追加されるコメント:

[image: possible duplicate of]

例: [「自分の質問を自分で回答したい？」のポップアップに表示されるボタンのキャプションが英語](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300/%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AE%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%82%92%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%A7%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%9D%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%9C%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%97%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8C%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E)

Answer (score 1):

- 重複？$questionLink$
- 重複かも: $questionLink$
- 重複候補: $questionLink$

日本語の文としては「...と重複しているかもしれません」が自然ですが、コメントの内容をすぐに把握できるように「重複」が先頭/前の方にあった方がよいと思います。

Comment: 「重複候補: $questionLink$」を利用するつもりです。